# Multiple Server 2012 guest OS in VMWare Workstation 10 with Bridged Networking

Tags: windows-server-2012, vmware-workstation, windows-8

I cant seem to be able to find out any details on this specifically.

Am I able to create multiple guest OS in wmare workstation 10 and connect them all directly to the host network via bridged connection?

Currently I only seem to be able to get one to connect at a time.

What i want is i have the host machine on the network 10.3.10.x and then the guest os also on this network so they can access and be accessed by both the host, other guests and other clients on the network.

Host: Win 8 Pro

Guest: Server 2012

Comment: What network adapter are you bridging to?

Comment: i have tried the automatic bridging for each guest os and i have tried setting custom network and selected vmnet0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause of this issue was Port Security on the Cisco switches.

This function limited the number of MAC addresses that were allowed to connect to the single port on the switch.

http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/switches/lan/catalyst6500/ios/12.2SX/configuration/guide/port_sec.html